# predicateForEventsWithStartDate function : Is this a bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

When using predicateForEventsWithStartDate function, it looks like the events returned lies in a time interval of around 4 years. Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it seems like a bug, me too had the same experience. The predicateForEventsWithStartDate: returns only events within a time interval of 4 years from the start date. All the other events lying outside the time interval wont be returned.

Comment: Haha! I am also experiencing this on iOS 7. My current workaround is to fetch events within [-1 year, +3 years].

Answer (score 0):

You can return events by choosing interval ( select start date and end date ) :

```
NSDateComponents *components = [CURRENT_CALENDAR components:DATE_COMPONENTS fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setDay:1];
[components setMonth:1];
[components setYear :[components year] - 1 ];
NSDate *startDate = [CURRENT_CALENDAR dateFromComponents:components];

NSDateComponents *EndComponents = [CURRENT_CALENDAR components:DATE_COMPONENTS fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[EndComponents setDay:1];
[EndComponents setMonth:1];
[EndComponents setYear:[EndComponents year] + 1];
NSDate *endDate = [CURRENT_CALENDAR dateFromComponents:EndComponents];

NSArray *calendarArray = nil;
if(systemVersion < 6.0)
{
     calendarArray = [yourEventStore calendars];
}
else
{
     calendarArray = [yourEventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
}
NSPredicate *predicate = [yourEventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray];
[arrayOfEvents addObjectsFromArray:[yourEventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Comment: @ Mohammad Rabi: The method is correct to retrieve the events, but returns the values that lies in a interval of 4 years from the start date.. Did you check the time interval ?

Comment: i edited the above answer for example you can fetch events from 1/1/2011 to 1/1/2013